# When does a log-convex function not form an positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: convex-analysis, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite, cholesky-decomposition, positive-matrices

If we consider the function $f(x)$ and the matrix A formed as follows

$$
A_{ij} = f(\frac{x_i + x_j}{2})
$$

and state that $f(x)$ is log-convex and non-negative

$$
f(x_1)^tf(x_2)^{(1-t)} \geq f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)
$$

Then the Cholesky decomposition for when $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix exists - if $A = LL^{T}$, then $L$ is given below
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
f(x_1)^{\frac{1}{2}} & 0 \\
f(\frac{x1 + x2}{2}) / f(x_1)^{\frac{1}{2}} & \left(f(x_2) - f(\frac{x1 + x2}{2})^2 / f(x_1)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{matrix} 
\right)
$$

Noting that by the definition of $f(x)$ as log-convex, the bottom right term will be non-negative within the square root, so the diagonals are real (as required).

By this answer on the [inductive proof of the cholesky decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509810/how-to-prove-the-existence-and-uniqueness-of-cholesky-decomposition) one can presumably generalise this, to show for $3\times3$ and so on for $(n+1)\times (n+1)$

My question is if there exist functions that are log-convex (or equivalently, where the log of the function is convex), that do not form a positive semi-definite matrix, as defined above?  I can't see how this can be true, but in some papers and lectures and so on I've seen the statement that if a matrix is defined as above and is positive semi-definite, then f is log-convex, but the other way around isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the statement that positive semi-definiteness of that matrix implies that $f$ is log-convex?

Comment: I don't have a link to the paper, but Corollary 2.4 and 2.5 in Exponential Convexity Method, J. Jaksetic and J. Pecaric